# Artificial LR grammar conflicts that shouldn't happen

Tags: parsing, lr-grammar

Consider an attempt at an LR grammar such as the following, where the quoted strings are assumed to be terminal symbols:

```
S: E
E: ("y" | "z") X A
E: ("y" | "z") X B
X: "x"
X:  X "x"
A: "a"
B: "b"
```

It would seem that this should be a conflict-free LR(1) grammar, because it is equivalent to

```
S: E
E: ("y" | "z") X (A | B)
X: "x"
X:  X "x"
A: "a"
B: "b"
```

Yet, I think(?) any real-world parser would mechanically translate it to

```
S: E
E: U X A
E: V X B
U: "y"
U: "z"
V: "y"
V: "z"
X: "x"
X:  X "x"
A: "a"
B: "b"
```

where `U` and `V` are symbols that are substituted directly by their children in the parse tree.

The resulting grammar is now LR(∞); it has reduce-reduce conflicts for LR(k < ∞) -- despite the fact that it really shouldn't!

Now, I realize it's possible to make this example much more complicated (say, using repetitions as well as disjunctions); in fact, as far as I can see, detecting such a situation reduces to testing the equivalence of two context-free grammars, which (if I remember correctly) is an undecidable problem.

My question is:

1. Am I correct that this is an actual problem, or am I missing a practical solution?
2. What is the best way to deal with this problem? Is reporting a conflict the best way, or are there heuristics that are used in practice to make the problem go away?

Comment: Why wouldn't the parser generator use the same nonterminal when replacing u | v? I'm not sure I see why you'd want to make two new nonterminals U and V.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I mean in this particular case it's easy because `u` and `v` are isomorphic, but to me it looks hard when that's not the case. For example, could a parser be smart enough to tell that `"a" "b" | "b" "b"*` is equivalent to `"a"? "b"+` if it sees a pattern like `(("a" "b" | "b" "b"*) | "a"? "b"+)`?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Any ideas? This question has literally only had 8 views in the past 3 months so I actually got pretty excited that you commented...

Comment: I wish I had something for you. Have you thought about using a different parsing algorithm like GLR or Earley? Those can handle the sorts of issues you're describing here perfectly. The other option might be to try to find "canonical forms" for the regex constructs that expose the underlying structure more easily, though regex minimization is known to be hard...

Comment: @templatetypedef: Ah :\ This is part of a GLR parser generator I wrote myself actually, and while it's a bit rough around the GLR edges, that's not the worry. I'm mostly trying to make it so that I can avoid GLR for grammars that are inherently LR(1) (or simpler), to make it easier for *other* people to write a parser for it. Mainly I'm just surprised here that no one had ever pointed this problem out to me or suggested a solution. I recently realized testing equivalences of regexes is decidable, so I might try to go that route.. but it seems pretty painful so I'm hoping I could get around it.

Comment: I've seen several examples of grammars where if you expand out a star one way it's not LR(1) but if you expand out stars in two different ways it becomes LR(1). I expect that this might just be kinda hard. :-/

Comment: @templatetypedef: Ah I see. On a philosophical note, what shocks me about the whole thing is that in math and CS, people always seem to treat the various "tricks" they teach as though they are flawless (like the introduction of auxiliary or slack variables, reductions to known problems, etc.) They never seem mention that there are tradeoffs and pitfalls that arise when you try to solve an "equivalent" problem instead of the original. But when I try to actually *apply* them, I realize reductions are costly and that the pitfalls were swept under the rug... apparently there's no free lunch! :P